# How to use Texture with a UImage as label in WhirlyGlobe

Tags: opengl-es, textures

I add WhirlyGlobe to my project, it works well. Now I need to add image as a mark, I use the code like this. But it seems not work well. 
The label show a white area on the top of first character. 
And the console log 'Texture::createInGL() glGenTextures()'.

What can I do to solve it.

```
Texture *theTex = new Texture(@"icon", @"png");
theTex->setUsesMipmaps(true);
SimpleIdentity theTexId = theTex->getId();
theScene->addChangeRequest(new AddTextureReq(theTex));
SingleLabel *gzLabel = [[[SingleLabel alloc] init] autorelease];
gzLabel.text = @"XXXXXX";
gzLabel.iconTexture = theTexId;
[gzLabel setLoc:GeoCoord::CoordFromDegrees(113.2759952545166, 23.117055306224895)];
[labels addObject:gzLabel];
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the texture a power of two along each side?

Comment: I'm sorry that I can't catch your meaning. I'm a newer to openGL, would you please explain it. Thank you.

Comment: Images that you feed to OpenGL need to be a power of two number of pixels along each size.  For instance, 256x256 or 512x512.